# Windows not working after setting up dual boot on Dell Inspiron 5570

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I have Dell Inspiron 5570, i5 8th gen, 2 TB Hard drive, 16GB Intel Optane and 8 GB RAM. I tried dual boot my PC with Ubuntu 16.04, but I was not getting any drive details. So I used terminal in live Ubuntu environment with following command:

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
```

After that Ubuntu was working and I installed it in a separate partition. But switching to Windows made it go to auto-repair which didn't work. And it said "Automatic Repair couldn't repair you PC"

Screenshot of the log file `C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt`

[image: 16 repair attempts]

I was unable to reset Windows without removing my files (didn't even try reset with file removal).

So I tried the following:

**Troubleshoot → Advanced Options → Command Prompt**. Then I typed:

```
chkdsk /f /r C:
EXIT
```

then exit and continue to Windows

But this didn't work though it took about 4-5 hrs to complete.

Then I tried the RegBack method, but I was unable to execute copy *.* .. command. Probably because my RegBack showed 0 files:

[image: 0 files copied]

Then I tried using `fixboot` but access was denied. To get back the access, I don't know what volume to select from the image below:

[image: 6 volumes]

Kindly tell me what should I do now to start my Windows (in dual boot) without deleting any data. Will fixboot help? If yes, then please tell me which volume should I select. I have already tried with volume 0. Also if there are other solutions, I will be happy to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Tangentially related question, why install Ubuntu 16.04 when 18.04 LTS and 19.10 non-LTS exist? Usually newer releases have better hardware support and as of 19.10 better performance via Gnome 3.34.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you... First of all: Are you messing with Veracrypt? Then this solution doesn't apply to you. 
At the beginning I suggest to update grub in case of it has old definitions... (But this could also make the matter worse...)
It is obvious that your Windows-Bootloader is broken. ("Always point out the obvious.") If you mean with fixboot the following, then it could and should help.

You've already gotten to the CMD of Windows, so try out the following:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildBcD
```

If that doesn't work: try `bootrec /ScanOs`If it doesn't find your Windows, you're in huge problems(that was mine...) So you see the Volume E, on this is the Efi bootloader. Switch to this partition in CMD and retry. And then follow this : https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows solution.

If that all failes, I advise: Save all necessary data and reinstall windows, on the same partition. Because the chance of sucess is not that high anymore and even if you're sucessfull probably not worth the work...

But no matter what, at the end you should use `update-grub`to bring GRUB up-to-date...

I wish you luck, that you don't have to reinstall windows.

Comment: I tried bootrec before. The fixboot access was denied. I tried to fix this issue but the access was still denied. I tried with volume 0 (see last pic attached in original question). Should I change volume? If so, then what should I select?

Comment: Your Microsoft Bootloader ist Probably on Volume 5 (=E. Because of the Size and the Name). (Or on 2 Because of Size and Filesystem)So you should try it with those. But to be honest: I'm not optimistic... If that all fails you should copy all important files to ubuntu and reinstall windows on the same partition (Yes, that is possible, with almost no problems)